# ActiveMQ 5.15.11 Java version support

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am updating my ActiveMQ to version 5.15.11. My application uses Java 1.7.x, but when I run my application using activemq-all5.15.11.jar I get the error below.

ActivMQ documentation says ActiveMQ 5 requires Java 7 then why I am getting major/minor version error?

Anyone know what Java version needed to run activemq-all-5.15.11.jar?

```
problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Comment: Did you get an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the [release notes for ActiveMQ 5.15.0](https://activemq.apache.org/activemq-5150-release) that the minimum Java version moved to 8.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ v5.15.x requires Java version 8 and above to run, and is tested on Java 8 specifically.  This move was made upon release of the v5.15.0 broker.